# If $H$ is a subgroup of index $2$ in $G$. Does the left coset $xH$ equals the right coset $Hx$, for every $x$ in $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm not sure how I can prove or show this

Comment: If $H$ has index $2$, there are exactly two distinct left cosets and two right cosets.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $G$ can be written as disjoint union of cosets.

$G=H\cup xH=H\cup Hx\implies xH=Hx$ For $x\in G-H$ and

if $x\in H$ then it is trivially true since $xH=H=Hx$. By the way that means that $H$ is normal in $G$.

Answer (score 0):

If $H$ is a subgroup of index $2$ in $G$, then for any $x\in G\setminus H$ we have
$$xH\ =\ G\setminus H\ =\ Hx\,.$$